# Set langage on Speech recognition plugin on Cordova

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, speech-recognition

I want to add a speech recognition on my mobile app builds with ionic 1.7.16. I'm looking for a good plugin which can work on Android and Ios.

Here the list of plugin that I found on internet and the reason why i don't use them :

- XSpeechRecognizer : Only for Android
- annyang : Doesn't work on Ios
- Google speech to text : Only for Android
- SpeechRecognizer : Only for
  Android

It's pity especially for Annyang.js which is really good library.

So I found SpeechRecognitionPlugin. However, the default langage recognized is English. I would like to change it by French.

On github : [https://github.com/macdonst/SpeechRecognitionPlugin][1] it's written that i can change the langage. However i didn't find any documentation.

Do you know how to change langage in for the app understand French langage for example ?

Thank's for your answers.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I've added Speech Recognition in my Ionic app for both platform with this solution and it works quite well in Italian for example:

FIRST: install this plug-in  `https://github.com/pbakondy/cordova-plugin-speechrecognition`

HTML:

```
  <div class="row bar-search-container">

            <div class="item-input-inset bar-search col-80">
                <label class="item-input-wrapper">
                    <input type="search" placeholder="Cerca" data-ng-model="brand.text" data-ng-change="brand.checkSearch()">
                </label>
                <span data-ng-click="brand.search()"><i class="icon ion-ios-search placeholder-icon icon-search-products"></i></span>
            </div>

            <div class="col microphone">
                <button class="mic-button {{micstate}}" data-ng-click="recordBrand()">
                    <i class="icon ion-mic-a placeholder-icon mic"></i>
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
```

My Controller JS:

```
     var vm = this;
     vm.micstate = "pause";
     vm.recordBrand = _record;


      /*
            * Function to Translate Voice in Text 
            */
            function _record() {
                //var recognition = new webkitSpeechRecognition(); //To Computer
                var recognition = new SpeechRecognition(); // To Device
                if (!recognition) return;

                recognition.lang = 'it-IT'; //<-- HERE YOU SET YOUR PREFERRED LANGUAGE!!!


                recognition.onaudiostart = function () {
                    vm.micstate = "listening";
                    $scope.$apply();
                };

                recognition.onaudioend = function () {
                    vm.micstate = "pause";
                    $scope.$apply();
                };

                recognition.onresult = function (event) {
                    if (event && event.results && event.results.length > 0) {
                        vm.text = event.results[0][0].transcript;
                        // search for products
                        _search();
                        $scope.$apply();
                    }
                };

                recognition.start();
            }


     //If text search length=0 set searchFilter.words=[]
            function _checkSearch() {
                if (vm.text.length === 0) {
                    vm.reset = true;
                    _search();
                }
            }

            /**
             * Function to search Brand on input on BACK END API (with pagination)
             * @param {string} input 
             * @returns {} 
             */
            function _search() {
                if (!vm.text && vm.reset === false) return;
//here I'm doing a call to back end API with text getted from speech recognition and plus pagination
                Brand.Get(vm.text, 0, take).$promise.then(function (resp) {
                    vm.brands = resp;
                });

            }
```

Hope it help you !!! ..